# How can i change the list of tables heading font

Tags: sectioning, formatting

I have to make all the headings with 12 pt.s bold. How can i change predefined headings like list of tables generated with command `\listoftables` ?

(and content page of course)

Here is all packages i'm using.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{pslatex}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalsize\bfseries\itshape}

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\fontsize{12}{14.4}\bfseries\MakeUppercase}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\usepackage[overload]{textcase} 
\usepackage[left=3.50cm, right=2.50cm, top=3.00cm, bottom=3.00cm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Please compose a fully compatible [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it. From the text of your question as it is now, it is impossible to help you.

Comment: oh i didn't know that, sorry

Comment: Commands like `\listoffigures` render differently in `article`, `report` and `memoir` for instance, that's why MWE. If I understand it right, you want to have the section title text size 12pt, and document text size 12pt as well?

Comment: Yes. Heading and normal size must be 12pts. Actually this is MS Word template because my school not providing ant TeX template, but i can do it in TeX, right?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `pslatex`, but rather `mathptmx`, in order to get Times-like fonts for your document. Chances are good that even without loading such packages the paper will be accepted with a "how nice this Times font" comment. :-)

Comment: Yea i guess. But "Times New Roman" is a must.

Comment: @interlude anyways, +1 and thumbs up for you to *want* to typeset your project in LaTeX when Word is standard at your school!

Comment: @tohecz Thanks. I literally HATE Word. It is a pain. No, it is agony! I tried to convince Word to do what i want for six hours at the last day of report deadline. I will not ever use Word again

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [titlesec](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package to customize the sectional unit titles. Since `\listoffigures` produces the title using `\section*`, the change in formatting for `\section` will affect this list (and every other element which internally uses `\section` or its starred variant). Since the 12pt class option is being used, it is enough to use `\normalsize`; the `explicit` option was used to be able to handle the case change in the titles. I also incorporated to my answer the settings for `\subsection` and `\subsubsection` that you included in your edited question:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage[left=3.50cm, right=2.50cm, top=3.00cm, bottom=3.00cm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[overload]{textcase} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{#1}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\itshape}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{#1}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures
\section{Test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: it's not working. Can it be about babel turkish package?

Comment: @interlude: then please edit your question and add a minimal version of your code in which the solution I proposed doesn't work; I ask for this minimal version because adding `\usepackage[turkish]{babel}` to my example, still shows the desired output, so something else is going on in your document.

Comment: Ok. I've edited the question. Thank you. I dont understand how things effect each other in TeX

Comment: @interlude: please see my updated answer.

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you. Weirdly when i changed the order of packages it worked perfectly. For now =)